# Possibly access ES6 generator return value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
var f = (function* (){
  yield 1;
  return 2;
})()

console.log(f.next().value) // 1
f.next()
```

Then how's it possible to access the return value 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting it, and ignoring it. The last line of your code, `f.next()`, returns `{value: 2, done: true}`.

```
var f = (function* (){
  yield 1;
  return 2;
})()

console.log(f.next().value) // 1
f.next().value // 2
```